# How can I pattern match a tuple containing a &mut enum and use the enum in the match arm?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, borrow-checker

How can the code below be made to compile? It seems perfectly safe, but can't convince the compiler that it is.

The version matching `*self` gives the error: `cannot move out of borrowed content` on the line of the match

The version matching `self` gives: `use of moved value: *self`

```
enum Foo {
    Foo1(u32),
    Foo2(i16),
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, y: u32) -> (u32, &mut Foo) {
        match (*self, y) {
            (Foo::Foo1(ref mut a), b) if (b == 5) => {
                print!("is five");
                *a = b + 42;

                (b, self)
            }

            (Foo::Foo2(ref mut a), b) if (b == 5) => {
                print!("is five");
                *a = (b + 42) as i16;

                (*a * b, self)
            }

            _ => {
                print!("is not five!");
                (y, self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I would need a match arm such as the following, but it doesn't seem to be valid syntax:

```
(ref mut f @ Foo::Foo1, b) if (b == 5) => {
    print!("is five");
    f.0 = b + 42;
    (b, f)
}
```

```
error[E0532]: expected unit struct/variant or constant, found tuple variant `Foo::Foo1`
  --> src/main.rs:24:30
   |
24 |                 (ref mut f @ Foo::Foo1, b) if (b == 5) => {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^ not a unit struct/variant or constant
```

Comment: "It seems perfectly safe", my C code seems perfectly safe too, but rust is not about "seems" but "is"

Comment: I'm reading through the linked questions now, but your solution still gives me `use of moved value: *self`

Comment: Note that I am trying to also return self, where the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not safe. You are attempting to introduce *mutable aliasing* inside the match arm. The mutable reference `a` points into the same value  as `self`. It would be possible to change `self` (e.g. `*self = Foo::Foo1(99)`) which would then invalidate `a`, so this code is disallowed.

Instead, *mutably reborrow* `self` in the `match` statement and have it return the first value of the tuple. Since this value doesn't have a reference to `self`, you can then return `self` with the result of the `match`:

```
enum Foo {
    Foo1(u32),
    Foo2(u32), // changed so I don't have to figure out what casting you meant
}

impl Foo {
   fn bar(&mut self, y: u32) -> (u32, &mut Foo) {
        let next = match (&mut *self, y) {
            (Foo::Foo1(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                b
            }

            (Foo::Foo2(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                *a * b
            }

            _ => y,
        };

        (next, self)
    }
}
```

However, returning `self` like this is rather pointless here. The caller *already* has a `&mut Foo`, so you don't need to "give it back". This allows simplifying to:

```
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, y: u32) -> u32 {
         match (self, y) {
            (Foo::Foo1(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                b
            }

            (Foo::Foo2(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                *a * b
            }

            _ => y,
        }
    }
}
```

> I would still say it is a safe operation, although the compiler may not be able to understand that

With [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423), the borrow checker becomes more intelligent. Your original code with an added explicit reborrow compiles:

```
#![feature(nll)]

enum Foo {
    Foo1(u32),
    Foo2(u32), // changed so I don't have to figure out what casting you meant
}

impl Foo {
   fn bar(&mut self, y: u32) -> (u32, &mut Foo) {
        match (&mut *self, y) {
            (Foo::Foo1(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                (b, self)
            }

            (Foo::Foo2(a), b @ 5) => {
                *a = b + 42;
                (*a * b, self)
            }

            _ => (y, self),
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why does matching on a tuple of dereferenced references not work while dereferencing non-tuples does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48044295/155423)
- [What is the syntax to match on a reference to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36590549/155423)
- [How can I use match on a pair of borrowed values without copying them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28530338/155423)
- [Is there any difference between matching on a reference to a pattern or a dereferenced value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the input - although the aliasing only happens during return, so I would still say it is a safe operation, although the compiler may not be able to understand that. However your answer also points out that my example was dumbed down too much - In the real scenario the data structure is self-referencing and I am actually returning a subtree of the original one, I'll adjust my question to better reflect this

Comment: @ÁkosVandra editing questions such that they invalidate existing answers is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Sorry, reverted the change, and submitted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330147/how-can-i-pattern-match-a-tuple-containing-a-mut-enum-and-use-the-enum-in-the-m

Comment: @ÁkosVandra and my edit about NLL doesn't happen to address your concern?